# Displaying text from input using trustAsHtml with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to search text from the input field in my array of objects and I need to add class with color to text when it is found (replace found text with the same text but colored). Here is my code:

```
input(
    ng-model="listCtrl.searchText"
    ng-change = "listCtrl.searchHighlight()"
    placeholder="{{list.SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER}}"
  )
```

and the piece of template code:

```
  div(ng-repeat="(key, apiKey) in listCtrl.List | filter:listCtrl.searchText track by apiKey.id" id="apiKey{{key}}")
```

and controller:

```
function searchHighlight() {
                const fields = ['name', 'publicKey'];
                const copy = [...listCtrl.List];
                copy.forEach((item, key) => {
                    Object.keys(item).forEach(field => {
                        if (fields.includes(field)) {
                            copy[key][field] = $sce.trustAsHtml(listCtrl.searchText ? item[field].toString()
                                .replace(new RegExp(`(${listCtrl.searchText})`, 'i'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
                                : item[field].toString());
                        }
                    });
                });
                listCtrl.List = copy;
            }
```

Search method is working right but after replace it shows like span class="highlighted" $1 /span except of needed text and that's the problem.